# billingaddress in Shopware Subscriber after registration

Tags: symfony4, shopware, shopware6

good morning,

i try to read the customer billing adress in Shopware 6 Subscriber since many hours.
In controllers i can use:

```
$SalesChannelContext->getCustomer()->getActiveBillingAddress()
```

but SalesChannelContext isnt available in Subscribers->EntityWrittenEvent so that this method isnt work. Injection through services.xml isnt work (because SCC isnt a Service?)
I tried to get the customer data throug the customer entity like this:

```
$customerRepo = $this->container->get('customer.repository');
$criteria = (new Criteria())
              ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $id));
       
$customer = $customerRepo->search( $criteria, $context);
```

The Customer was found but the addresses (billing and delivery) are null so thats the wrong way too.
Has anyone an idea to solve this problem?

What i need: Method to get billing address
What i get: customer object with address => null
ways to solve: make saleschannelcontext available should be the best idea?!

thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 3):

Which event do you subscribe to? Many events have the `SalesChannelContext` as property, maybe you can get it from there.

The `SalesChannelContext` is not a service because it is an object which represents the current state of the request. So something which has to be created newly on every request.

If you have the customer ID, it is quite simple to get its data, as you already find out. What you are missing is the association to the billing address. By default, associations are normally not loaded with the main entity, due to performance reasons. But you can add them in the `Criteria` object:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $id));
$criteria->addAssociation('defaultBillingAddress');
// $criteria->addAssociation('activeBillingAddress'); if you want the current active address, might differ from the default one
// $criteria->addAssociation('addresses'); if you want all addresses
       
$customer = $this->customerRepo->search( $criteria, $context);
```

But before you select the customer with another query, I would try to get the `SalesChannelContext` from the event.

Comment: to add Association is the correct answer. Thanks. I subscribed (for the moment) the EntityWrittenEvent to test my code. There is no SalesChannelContext, or i didnt found by standard way. BUT! The SalesChannelContext is available through the $request:  `$requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('sw-sales-channel-context')` both solutions are working now. :)

Comment: please make sure, that you always check if the `SalesChannelContext` object is set and not `null`. because the EntityWrittenEvent is of course also dispatched in other contexts like the admin API

Answer (score 2):

The salesChannelContext is not globally available, as it is just available if the request originates from the storefront. If you are in Admin-API context, or even CLI context, for example there is no SalesChannelContext available.

In general your solution for fetching the customer from the DB looks like the right approach.

You ran into problems because the Shopware DAL (DataAbstractionLayer) does not load associations of entities by default, you have to define what associations you want to load with the main entity beforehand.

In your case this would be accomplished by this:

```php
$customerRepo = $this->container->get('customer.repository');
$criteria = (new Criteria())
              ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $id))
              ->addAssociation('defaultBillingAddress');
       
$customer = $customerRepo->search( $criteria, $context);
$customer->getDefautBillingAddress();
```

Notice the `addAssociation()` call here. You can find details explained [here](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/developer-guide/database#enriching-results-with-associations).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thats the correct answer, like above,  too. In Symfony i get all Collections by default thatswhy this way is new to me. Thx.